# with lxml Inserting a parsed xml file as an Element for subsequent output

Tags: python-3.x, lxml

I have an application that uses lxml to creating some xml and currently one section is an embedded include of another xml file

Problem is that when I save the file I need to also save the included xml in the same directory.

What I am looking for is that when I create the Element Tree and get to the section that currently I set for include that actually I parse the include file such that it becomes part of the Element Tree and will be part of the output.

I am creating a GDML file so my app has (Obviously it outputs a more detailed Element Tree)

```
gdml = ET.Element('gdml')
define = ET.SubElement(gdml, 'define')
structure = ET.SubElement(gdml, 'structure')
setup = ET.SubElement(gdml, 'setup', {'name': 'Default', 'version': '1.0'})
ET.SubElement(setup,'world', {'ref':self.Name})
solids = ET.SubElement(gdml, 'solids')
```

Currently the materials section has

```
    ent  = ET.Entity("materials")
    materials = ET.SubElement(gdml, 'materials')
    materials.append(ent)
```

Which when I output the file requires that the file to be embedded materials.xml is in the same directory.

I would like to parse the materials xml file and add to the Element Tree
        `materials = ET.parse("./materials.xml")`

How can I get materials added to the gdml ET.Element

Comment: If I had a minimal reproducible example I would not be asking the question.

Comment: I am looking for a suggestion of how the problem might be handled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add whatever is in materials.xml like this:

```
# Parse materials.xml and get the root element
materials = ET.parse("materials.xml").getroot()

# Append materials as a new child of the gdml root element
gdml.append(materials)
```

Comment: Yeah, `parse()` returns an `ElementTree` object, but `append()` expects an `Element`.